# Android QR bitmap need help to remove margin

Tags: java, android, bitmap, pixel

I have encoded a String into a QR bitmap. The picture becomes like this:

[image: image of QR bitmap]

What do I need to change so that there is no whitespaces around the QR? I tried to read on the documentation about MultiFormatWriter() and setPixels(), but couldn't find out where it is wrong. 
Here is the code:

```
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws  WriterException {
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return null;
    }

    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int [w * h];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        int offset = i * w;
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            pixels[offset + j] = result.get(i, j) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
     }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 500, 0, 0, w, h);
    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use hints param for set custom margins.

```
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<>(EncodeHintType.class);
hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, marginSize);
BitMatrix result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(contentsToEncode, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, imageWidth, imageHeight, hints);
```

Comment: Works nicely. In Kotlin you could write it as `val hints = mapOf(EncodeHintType.MARGIN to marginSize)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you set your pixels in the Bitmap.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> stride    int: The number of colors in pixels[] to skip between rows. Normally this value will be the same as the width of the bitmap, but it can be larger (or negative).

So I suggest the following:

```
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

**Edit:**
Just noticed you assume that the input's size is 500. you can try to compute it (assuming your string represents a square). If it is a rectangle, you have to be able to compute the size somehow so the MultiFormatWriter can read it.

So your code can be:

```
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str, int size) throws  WriterException {

    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] pixels = new int [size * size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int offset = i * size;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            pixels[offset + j] = result.get(i, j) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
     }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, size, 0, 0, size, size);
    return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: It still outputs an image with margins :(

Comment: The update gives the ImageView width and height of str.length(), and it makes the ImageView not visible. But that is good direction to go forward, we probably need the length(maybe?) of the result.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the input string is. Perhaps you can drop the sqrt or find some other way of computing the height and width.

Comment: The input string is input from an EditText

Comment: If you can't infer the size from the input - perhaps you can just provide it from the calling method - for example the device's width in pixels.

Comment: Had to add into the method with encodeHintType as a map, where I pass the map into the last parameter in encode(). It looks great now, thanks Doron!